# An example for plural forms in a Yaml translation file for Rails i18n API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, yaml, gettext

Can someone please provide an example on how to use plural forms in a Yaml translation file for Rails i18n API. Basically this is about moving from a gettext based app to Rails.

Plural forms for a18n in Rails is documented here  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#pluralization but with limited detail.

Say for example I have this sample from a gettext .po file that uses plural forms:

```
msgid "found %d fatal error"
msgid_plural "found %d fatal errors"
msgstr[0] "s'ha trobat %d error fatal"
msgstr[1] "s'han trobat %d errors fatals"
```

How would that look in a .yml file for the Rails i18n API. I understand that Rails i18n uses unique id keys rather than the messages themselves for translation keys - so lets say the key for the above plural messages is found_x_fatal_error.

The other thing is the plural forms selection formula, where does it go in the .yml file and how does it look - say for example we have this selection formula from a gettext .po file header:

```
Plural-Forms: nplurals=2; plural=n == 1 ? 0 : 1;
```

How would it look in the YAML file.

Comment: I think this thread might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166064/i18n-pluralization

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can configure more options:

```
error_msg:
  zero: none
  one: 1 error
  other: %{count} errors

t('error_msg', :count => 15)
=> 15 errors
```

Depending on the version of I18n it will be {{count}} or %{count} in the yml file. More explanation can be found here:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#pluralization