# Rails plural rules for translations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, rails-i18n

I am trying to translate some counter of items according to the grammar of the language. I faced with an issue that [doc](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html) says about plural forms and they are different for each language. I expected that [rules](http://unicode.org/repos/cldr-tmp/trunk/diff/supplemental/language_plural_rules.html) are already inside `I18n` and what I need to do is just fill translations. But when I read the code of `pluralize` method at `i18n/backend/base.rb`

```
   def pluralize(locale, entry, count)
      return entry unless entry.is_a?(Hash) && count

      key = :zero if count == 0 && entry.has_key?(:zero)
      key ||= count == 1 ? :one : :other
      raise InvalidPluralizationData.new(entry, count) unless entry.has_key?(key)
      entry[key]
    end
```

I found that it supports only `en`. For example I am working now on arabic translation.

```
I18n.backend.store_translations :ar, path: { one: 'one', two: 'two', other: 'other', many: 'many', few: 'few'}
```

Here I filled translation backend and I expect that if I pass `count` option 11 then I receive `:many` translation as specified by the language plural rules.

```
I18n.t :path, count: 11, locale: :ar #should return 'many'
```

Do I need to specify those rules myself? Then where? Or do I need swizzle something?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [i18n Pluralization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166064/i18n-pluralization)

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own rules, for this, you can create the file: 
config/initializers/inflections.rb
and adapt this example to your reality:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
  inflect.plural /^(ox)$/i, '\1\2en'
  inflect.singular /^(ox)en/i, '\1'

  inflect.irregular 'octopus', 'octopi'

  inflect.uncountable 'equipment'
end
```

Take a look in the documentation:
[Inflections](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector/Inflections.html)

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6166091/962964) answer solved my issue. I need enable loading mode for custom plural rules and then specify keyword for each case.

Comment: If you find a duplicate, please close your question as such.