# Rails i18n pluralization: Infinity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, rails-i18n

My app's pricing plan has some features that are unlimited. For example in the "Pro" version you get 10 forms, and in the "Unlimited" version you get unlimited forms.

This is represented in the Plan model by an integer or Float::Infinity.

```
pro = Plan.find_by name: 'Pro'
pro.forms_limit
#=> 10

unl = Plan.find_by name: 'Unlimited'
unl.forms_limit
#=> Float::INFINITY
```

In the view:

```
= t('.forms', count: plan.forms_limit)
```

I am trying to find an efficient way to interpolate this with I18n. What I'd like to do is:

```
plans:
  index:
    forms: 
      zero: No Forms
      one: 1 Form
      other: "%{count} Forms"
      infinity: Unlimited Forms
```

This will work, but it results in undesired output like:

```
"Infinity Forms"
```

Is there a way to structure this so that Infinity will  interpolate "Unlimited" instead of "Infinity"?

Comment: You need to use quotes when providing strings for interpolation `other: "%{count} Forms"`. In YAML `%` is (rarely) used to give special directives to the interpreter. http://www.yaml.org/refcard.html

Comment: Thanks, good catch. That's what was causing the exception. I rephrased the question; I still want to interpolate "Unlimited" in place of "Infinity".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a file `config/locales/plurals.rb` with the following

```
{
  en: {
    i18n: {
      plural: {
        keys: [:one, :other, :infinity],
        rule: lambda do |n|
          if n == 1
            :one
          elsif n == Float::INFINITY
            :infinity
          else
            :other
          end
        end
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and then in my `config/locales/en.yml`, I have

```
en:
  forms:
    zero: 'No Forms'
    one: '1 Form'
    other: '%{count} Forms'
    infinity: 'Unlimited Forms'
```

added in `config/initializers/locale.rb`

```
I18n::Backend::Simple.send(:include, I18n::Backend::Pluralization)
```

and testing it in IRB

```
I18n.t(:forms, count: 0)
# => "No Forms"
I18n.t(:forms, count: 1)
# => "1 Form"
I18n.t(:forms, count: 10)
# => "10 Forms"
I18n.t(:forms, count: Float::INFINITY)
# => "Unlimited Forms"
```

#### What is this doing?

This isn't nearly as mysterious as I thought when. I first tried it (getting the idea from [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6166091/8255744).

When you include [I18n::Backend::Pluralization](https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n/blob/master/lib/i18n/backend/pluralization.rb) it's going to start looking for a key `i18n.plural.rule` that should respond to call, anywhere in the load path. So the `plurals.rb` file name is unimportant, just need to make sure it's a file in `I18n.load_path`.

We make that file a ruby file with a hash so that we can set that `i18n.plural.rule` key to a lambda (so it responds to `call`) and then the lambda gets called with the count getting passed in. As pointed out there are

Comment: Edited. `finite?` is defined by `Float` so calling `finite?` on a Fixnum causes a `NoMethodError`.

Comment: Perfect, exactly what i was looking for. One thing I'm confused about - why is `config/locales/plural.rb` a hash, and what is picking that up? Also how did you figure this out? I read through the source at https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n and was looking at this all wrong.

Comment: @mysmallidea I picked it up from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166064/i18n-pluralization) since it's from 2011 and I was unsure if it would still work I throw together an example of what you were wanting in my test app and it still seems to work. I'm still trying to work through the 'how' of it all and why that hash myself, I'll update my answer if I get anywhere in finding anything out

Comment: @max it appears you're correct, I'm in ruby 2.4 which doesn't have Fixnum anymore (and Numeric has finite? so when I tested an integer everything worked), I'll update the answer

Comment: Ah, I tested it on 2.3.1 which explains why I got an error.

Comment: @mysmallidea think I've got it figured out, actually pretty simple really. I was thinking it was some rails configuration magic (thus I was looking in ActiveSupport for all of this), but it's just part of the normal i18n gem